# What should be the proper reply for thanks?

Tags: word-choice, british-english, politeness, subcontinental-english

I like a girl which is in same division as I am. Recently she was suffering from malaria and when I came to know this I sent a "Get well soon!" message. We have hardly exchanged any words in labs and common lectures.
Now she has replied as "thanks!" as expected. I want to give her a good reply for her thanks just to continue. So what should I say in this situation. I really like this girl!

Comment: This isn't really a question on the English language but because I'm a relationship guru (yeah, right!) I'll make a suggestion.  Ask her how she is feeling.  Then, when she says that she feels better, say "that is good to hear.  I was worried for you".  She will say "thanks" again.  Then you say "It mustn't have been nice; can I take you to dinner as a treat for you?".  Come back and thank me later.

Comment: Thanks to all.
@Ste how about these lines as our semester exams are on the verge.
"Welcome miss.
Keep up your health and mood."
Can you come up with more such lines as I mentioned? Or some good variations. It will be a great help.

Comment: Say hello and ask how she is feeling.  Tell her that you are glad she is feeling better and then, when she smiles and says thanks, wish her good luck in her exam and ask if she'd like to go to the movies with you.

Comment: 'Thanks' kind of shuts the conversation down, and sorry to say, doesn't invite a response. Best advice is to start a new conversation, like 'how are you feeling now?'

Comment: @Maverick: What country do you study in when you call your classmate "miss"???

Comment: @HonzaZidek, I know it's not common but I think there's nothing wrong in this usage as we can use 'sir' to refer to our friend formally or sarcastically or to get his attention if he is ignoring you or just to amuse him.

Comment: @Maverick, It's still odd, like *very* odd. malaria.... are you from India?

Answer (score 4):

The traditional English reply to thanks is to say "you're welcome" or various informal variants of that "it was nothing", "think nothing of it", "oh, any time", "my pleasure" and so on.

More generally, I think you need care less about that bit of the conversation. "You're welcome" suffices to reply to the thanks, but when someone has been sick, and enquiry after their well-being and expressing the hope that they are recovered should be the main part of your communiqué. But that stretches beyond questions about EL&U.

Comment: Thanks sir!
How about "You're welcome, Miss. Keep your health up."
Or it should be "You're welcome miss. Keep your health up."
Which one is correct grammatically?

Comment: "You're welcome" as a standard response to "thank you" is a very common context error. Here it would not really be appropriate. Just like with "happy birthday", "get well soon", "have a nice day". All of these might receive a thanks, but "you're welcome" would not be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people here are suggesting something along the lines of "you're welcome" or its more casual "no problem"  as a response to "thanks".

This is a very common mistake amongst non-native/L2 English speakers, as it is often learned that "thank you - you're welcome" is a standard pairing. However, there are contexts where it is not appropriate, and this is one of them.

Instead, you should say something that maintins the positive mood and attempts to keep a conversation going. You could try something like, "I hope you're feeling better" or "how are you feeling now?". These ahow that you are concerned while inviting her to reply again.

Answer (score -1):

"no need to mention" is a good sentence we can use

Comment: No need to mention **it**, I presume you mean...

Answer (score -1):

From [*The Kite Runner*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Kite_Runner):

> For you, a thousand times over.